# Outputting data to csv in python

Tags: python, output

I have data that this script outputs as a scatterplot of `ID_all[:,0],ID_all[:,1]`, but I want to also save the data used for the scatter plot as two columns (as a csv file). Any help really appreciated! Thanks in advance.

More Info:

Here is a link to the initial csv data so that you can see my problem (only first two columns used).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/966iviv01tccv1k/contacts.csv?dl=0

If you plot the input csv file (see figure 1), you will see that it only has half of the values that I need. So when I plot this with the below script, I transpose the 'matrix', making a mirror image of this vrt the main diagonal. Now with this script I plot both the original and the transpose (figure 2), but I somehow cannot figure out how to just output columns of data in addition to the figure. 
[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def parsefile(filename):
    i = 0
    print('Opening File')
    try:
        for line in open(filename):
            line = line.split()
            ID = np.hstack((int(line[0]), int(line[1])))
            if i==0:
                ID_list = ID
            i+=1
            if i>0:
                ID_list = np.vstack((ID_list, ID))
        print('File Opened')   
        return ID_list
    except:
        return ID_list

def get_scatter_data(ID_list):
    ID_swapped1 = ID_list[:, 1]
    ID_swapped2 = ID_list[:, 0]
    ID_swapped = np.transpose([ID_swapped1.T, ID_swapped2.T])
    N = np.max(ID_list)
    diagonal = np.linspace(1,N,N)
    ID_diagonal = np.transpose([diagonal.T,diagonal.T])
    ID_all = np.vstack((ID_list,ID_swapped,ID_diagonal))
    return ID_all

def plot_contactmap(ID_all, savefilename):
    f = plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(ID_all[:,0],ID_all[:,1], marker='o', s=0.01)
    plt.axis('square')
    plt.xlabel('Residue Number', fontsize = 14)
    plt.ylabel('Residue Number', fontsize = 14)
    plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
    plt.show()
    f.savefig(savefilename+'.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    f.savefig(savefilename+'.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')

def main(filename, savefilename):
    ID_list = parsefile(filename+'.csv')
    ID_all  = get_scatter_data(ID_list)
    plot_contactmap(ID_all, savefilename)

main('contacts', 'test')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save using `numpy.savetxt()` method

```py
import numpy as np
ID_all = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
np.savetxt('output.csv', ID_all, delimiter=',', fmt="%d")
```

If you want to give column names you can use `header` argument `np.savetxt()` method.

`np.savetxt('output.csv', ID_all, delimiter=',', header='first, second', fmt="%d")`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am not quite sure this is what I am looking for exactly. I added more descriptions to explain what I am trying to output in the output.csv as well as figures to explain it and the input file to test.

Comment: @mrsphd can you explain your expected output with an example. I'm not understood what are you saying?

Comment: So if you look at the code, the scatterplots are made from ID_all[:,0],ID_all[:,1] . I need those values not as a plot, but in a csv, such that values of ID_all[:,0] are in column 1 and  ID_all[:,1] in column 2.

Comment: @mrsphd my code also doing the same as per my example it saving `1, 3, 5` in one column and `2, 4, 6` in other column